# Add new row, increment last digit in alphanumerial string from cell below

Tags: vba, increment

New in VBA, did tried different examples available on the web but can't make it work as my string only increment by 1 & subsequent executions, the string stay the same.

Requirement:
Adding a line above row 47.
New cell A47 to increment last digit on alphanumerical string available in cell A48

My current code:

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Updt As String
Dim num As Integer
Dim DD As String
Dim TT As String
 
num = num + 1
 
Updt = "Update/Mise À Jour #"  'ALPHANUMERIC STRING TO INCREMENT
DD = Date
TT = Time
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CF")
 
    With Ws
       .Rows(47).Copy
       .Rows(47).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
       .Range("A47:E47").ClearContents
       .Range("B47") = DD & " " & TT
       .Cells(47, 1).Value = Updt & num
    End With

Any help will be apreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

After many trials, within my With, was able to make it work with this:

num = Right(Range"A48"), 2)
.Range("A47") = "Update/Mise À Jour # " & Format(Int(num) + 1, "00")